# Apache ReverseProxy sets upstream server to error when it returns an error page

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, failover, 500-error

We are using an Apache LoadBalancer/ReverseProxy to provide a failover for our web servers. Currently we are experiencing the following problem:

- A webservice call returns an error with HTTP status code 500
- Since `ProxyErrorOverride` is set to On, Apache overrides the response of the upstream server and replaces it with the default Apache error page. We added this directive to make sure no error details of the upstream server can get to the outside.
- Apache sets the upstream server to state "ERR" for a minute
- Subsequent requests are sent to another server, that isn't aware of the client session, so access is denied (we use sticky and not shared sessions)

Without `ProxyErrorOverride` the response of the upstream server is returned and the load balancer does NOT set it to state "ERR". I didn't find this side effect documented nor a workaround yet.

Any ideas? Some excerpts from our configuration file:

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    # ProxyErrorOverride On

    <Proxy balancer://jboss>
            BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=11 connectiontimeout=60
            BalancerMember http://server2:8080 route=12 connectiontimeout=60
            ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
    </Proxy>
```

httpd -v returns

`Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`